# Best way to handle if-else with try-catch

Tags: java

This is the blue print of the code

```
Object one = doSomeFetching();

if (one != null) {
    try {
        Object two = doSomeOperationXYZ(one);
        return two;
    } catch (ExceptionXYZ e) {
        throw e;
    }
} else {
    throw new ObjectIsNotPresentCustomerException(....);
}
```

if the object **one** is not null, then only I go to the function inside try and do something and return if all goes well, or throw an exception. 
If **one** is null, I simply return an exception.

The code structure some how doesn't seems good to me,
Can you suggest the best way to handle such cases

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can revert the check to eliminate the `else` and throw the exception first as

```
Object one = doSomeFetching();

if (null == one) {
    throw new ObjectIsNotPresentCustomerException(....);
}
try {
    Object two = doSomeOperationXYZ(one);
    return two;
} catch (ExceptionXYZ e) {
    throw e;
}
```

Comment: To add to the above answer: Code should keep related operations close to each other.  The original code has the error handling for `doSomeFetching` split by the `doSomeOperationXYZ` code.  That makes for more work understanding the code.  Imagine if the `doSomeOperationXYZ` code were more than a few lines.